# Table Issues in Latex

Tags: tables

Currently, I am working on a latex document but unfortunately, black cells appear on the head of the table while using table generator. Any idea?

Comment: Please show a compilable example code.

Comment: use of table generator is not good idea. result is in the most cases terrible. driect typing of tables in editor is not so complicated ... :-)